# Errors during LFS first boot

Tags: linux, grub, lfs

I just finished building my LFS system, but been running into issues during the first boot. The error that comes up is:

`hd1 cannot get c/h/s values`

So a little background:
The base machine I used was CentOS7 on a Virtual Machine running on ESX6. 
The sda was the drive for the base CentOS7 and a second drive for the LFS which is sdb. 
In this, sdb1 was my XFS / partition and sdb2 is my swap.

My Grub.cfg under /boot/grub/grub.cfg is:

```
# Begin /boot/grub/grub.cfg
set default=0
set timeout=5

insmod xfs
set root=(hd1,0)

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Test-Linux-1.0" {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.12.7-lfs-8.1 root=/dev/sdb1 ro
}
```

fstab entry is:

```
# Begin /etc/fstab

# file system  mount-point  type     options             dump  fsck
#                                                              order

/dev/sdb1     /             xfs    defaults            1     1
/dev/sdb2     swap         swap     pri=1               0     0
proc           /proc        proc     nosuid,noexec,nodev 0     0
sysfs          /sys         sysfs    nosuid,noexec,nodev 0     0
devpts         /dev/pts     devpts   gid=5,mode=620      0     0
tmpfs          /run         tmpfs    defaults            0     0
devtmpfs       /dev         devtmpfs mode=0755,nosuid    0     0
```

I tried changing to sda1 and sda2 in fstab and set root to sda1 in Grub along with hdd to 0,0 and still no luck.

Any thoughts? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, I was able to get past this. I had missed out on the VMXNET3 and SAS drivers. Lol, yeah I know! Now, it boots into `grub>` prompt. Not sure what's next.